# How to select dropdown lists with no id

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, excel, internet-explorer-8

I've been researching this for the last couple days but haven't found a solution yet. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm using VBA to put a push button on an Excel spreadsheet which will open an Internet Explorer window, log people into a particular site, search for a particular "case" (webform) on the site, fill in the values the way the user specified on the sheet, and then submit the form.  Everything works except the form fields that are drop down lists.  When I run it, it fills in the values I want in those fields but it seems like it's not actually selecting them from the list, just overwriting what's displayed there, because when it clicks submit an error window pops up saying to fill in those drop down fields.

From my research I've seen various solutions for how to search a drop down list and set it to the selected index once it's located the text I want, but my problem is that I haven't had luck selecting the drop down list at all.  If you look at the screenshot below, that shows one of the fields as it looks in Internet Explorer's dev tools:
[image: IE Dev tools]
[image]
The highlighted portion is the id number I use to paste in my text (what I'm doing right now that isn't working) but the line below it with class ns-dropdown seems like it might be what I really want to access, but that line doesn't have an id.

Here's the relevant portion of my code:

```
Dim IE As Object
Dim IEForm As HTMLDocument

Set IEForm = IE.Document

With IEForm
    .getElementById("custevent_crc_code_fs").innerText = Sheet1.Cells(9, 3) 'CRC Code
    .getElementById("inpt_status4").innerText = Sheet1.Cells(8, 3) 'Status
    .getElementById("inpt_custevent95").innerText = Sheet1.Cells(11, 3) 'Department
    .getElementById("inpt_custevent426").innerText = Sheet1.Cells(10, 3) 'Case Origin
    .getElementById("inpt_custevent447").innerText = Sheet1.Cells(6, 3) 'Created By
    .getElementById("inpt_custevent1188").innerText = Sheet1.Cells(7, 3) 'Contact Reason
    .getElementById("btn_multibutton_submitter").Click
End With
```

Let me know if you need any more information.  I've been wrestling with this for a while and am trying not to flood you with too much extraneous info about things I've tried.

Comment: When populating an `Input` you typically set the `Value` attribute, not the `innerText`

Comment: I never did find an answer to this, just ended up rewriting the whole thing in Python with Selenium to perform the actual clicks.